# For each next column, uncorrelate it with all the previous columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help developing this logic. I have a data frame of returns with 4 columns in total. Lets call the columns I1,I2,I3,I4.

I want to uncorrelate the data from I2 with I1. Then I want to Uncorrelate the data from I3 with I1 and I2. Lastly, I want to uncorrelate the data from I4 with I1,I2 and I3.

I'm trying to do this in an automatic way, so if I, later on, decide to add the 5th column I5, it would automatically uncorrelate it with I1,I2,I3 and I4.

I have evaluated the number of uncorrelation required using the Euler method.

Parameters:

s - Number of columns
unc - Uncorrelations needed

initial values:

s[0]=1 and unc[0]=0   # If only 1 column exists, no uncorrelation needed

Euler formula for this:
unc[n+1]=s[n]+unc[n]
&
s[n+1]=s[n]+1

So for example, if a new column is added,

unc[1] = s[0] + unc[0] = 1 + 0 = 1  #1 uncorrelation needed
s[1] = s[0]+1 = 1 +1 = 2

If another column is added (that makes 3 columns now)

unc[2] = s[1]+unc[1] = 2 + 1 = 3  # 3 unccorelations needed

And the process continues.

But the problem is, I don't know how I would apply this logic to python code.

Here is an example data frame and a function I'm using to uncorrelate the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

d = {'I1':[10,20,30,40,50], 'I2':[11,21,31,41,51], 'I3':[12,22,32,42,52], 'I4':[13,23,33,43,53]}
some_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def linear_regression_model(main_data, data_i_want_to_uncorrelate):
    
    lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    model = lm.fit(main_data, data_i_want_to_uncorrelate)
    X_variable = model.coef_
    Intercept = model.intercept_

    uncorelated_index1 = data_i_want_to_uncorrelate[data_i_want_to_uncorrelate.columns[0]] - (Intercept[0]+X_variable[0]*main_data[main_data.columns[0]])
    

    return uncorelated_index1
```

Appreciate the help and the time you take to help me out in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for some kind of matrix factorization of your data matrix X, which let's say has N rows and p columns with N>=p (in your specific case, N=5, p=4). I'd consider QR factorization, i.e. X=Q*R Q is NxN orthogonal and R is Nxp upper triangular. Let's call the first p columns of Q by the name Q1 and the remaining columns by the name Q2, while the first p rows of R will be called R1 (since R is upper triangular, the remaining rows are 0). Then Q1 gives the decorrelated columns in your new dataframe. The (default) "reduced" mode in QR factorization will only give you Q1 and not compute Q2.

```
import numpy as np
X = some_dataframe.values
N, p = X.shape
Q1, R = np.linalg.qr(X)
decorrelated_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=Q1)
```

If a new column, call it x, is now added onto X, then the decorrelated version will simply be x-Px, where P is the projection matrix onto the column space of Q1, i.e. P=Q1*Q1.T (after some simplification).

```
x = some_dataframe.loc[:,'new_column']
decorrelated_dataframe.loc[:,'new_column'] = x - np.matmul(x, np.matmul(Q1, Q1.T))
```